# Cannot resend expired email invite to a team

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm trying to add new users to a private team. It is great to have the opportunity to have groups of up to 50 users for free!

Now, after sending the invite, some users missed it. The invite expired, but when I try to send it again I get the error message:

> This email already has a pending invite: XXX@gmail.com.

Comment: It's a little hard to diagnose the issue without more info, specifically the email address that's having the issue. Since I don't want you to disclose that publically, can you open a ticket https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/26 so we can look into this?